# Menu Expand and Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to be able to expand and collapse Manu Nav on my company website such as when someone is using a Mobile device to access my website, if click on Nav Icon it opens at the front of my company website where you will see the same Manu Nav that was hidden unless when click Nav Icon on a mobile device and Manu Nav appears, which works fine.

But someone clicks on li tags it expand the contains of the li tags which ul tags inside li tags, like when i have Domains and under it i have, Single Domain Register, Bulk Domain Register, Transfer Domains, New TLDs in desktop device when you hover over it shows this contains and in mobile device when you click on Manu Nav Icon it opens the Domains, Hosting, etc.

So what i want to do is when someone clicks on Domains it slides down its contains and if click on Hosting its slides up the Domains contains and slides down the Hosting contains.

Here is what i have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".parents-toggle > li a").click(function () {
        $(".parents-toggle > div.menu-toggle").not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
        $(this).siblings(".menu-toggle").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden { 
    display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="parents-toggle">
    <li>
        <a  href="#" id="domain-toggle">Domains</a>
        <div class="menu-toggle hidden" id="domain-menu">
            <div class="menu-toggle-one">
                <ul>
                    <li><a  href="http://www.domain.com/domain">Simple Domain Search</a></li>
                <li><a  href="http://www.domain.com/index.php?m=newtlds">New TLDs</a></li>
                <li><a  href="http://www.domain.com/domainchecker.php?search=bulkregister">Bulk Domain Search</a></li>
                <li><a  href="http://www.domain.com/domainchecker.php?search=bulktransfer">Bulk Domain Transfer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
<div class="parents-toggle">
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="domain-toggle">Hosting</a>
        <div class="menu-toggle hidden" id="domain-menu">
            <div class="menu-toggle-one">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Hosting/Shared">Shared Hosting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Hosting/VPS">VPS Servers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Hosting/Reseller">Reseller Hosting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Hosting/Dedicated">Dedicated Servers</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

But when clicks nothing shows up can someone please let me know what might be the problem what is missing and what do i need to add to make it work
my company website can be found here: https://www.domain.com if my question is confusing let me know.

Thanks

Comment: change your selector `$(".parents-toggle > div.menu-toggle")` to `$(".parents-toggle > li > div.menu-toggle")`

Comment: thanks i have tried that but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JS to Following, It will close first drop-down if second opens.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".parents-toggle > li a").click(function () {
       //$(".parents-toggle > div.menu-toggle").not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
       $(".parents-toggle").siblings().find('.menu-toggle').slideUp();
       $(this).siblings(".menu-toggle").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="parents-toggle">
    <li><a  href="#" id="domain-toggle">Domains</a>
        <div class="menu-toggle hidden" id="domain-menu">
            <div class="menu-toggle-one">
                <ul>
                    <li><a  href="http://www.domain.com/domainchecker.php">Simple Domain Search</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="http://www.domain.com/index.php?m=newtlds">New TLDs</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="http://www.domain.com/domainchecker.php?search=bulkregister">Bulk Domain Search</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="http://www.domain.com/domainchecker.php?search=bulktransfer">Bulk Domain Transfer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>

<div class="parents-toggle">
    <li><a href="#" id="domain-toggle">Hosting</a>
        <div class="menu-toggle hidden" id="domain-menu">
            <div class="menu-toggle-one">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Hosting/Shared">Shared Hosting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Hosting/VPS">VPS Servers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Hosting/Reseller">Reseller Hosting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Hosting/Dedicated">Dedicated Servers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3w07hxh/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have change my js to the one you provided but it doesn't open when click.

Comment: It does open here http://jsfiddle.net/e3w07hxh/, you have jQuery library included?

Comment: yes i have jquery and yes it works on Fiddle but i don't seems to recall why is not working on my side

Comment: Its the top main nav menu on your site? if it is, its working right and use the updated code in answer, i replace the id with class

Comment: what jquery should i use maybe the one i am using is outdated or something because is not working, the Mobile Device Nav Icon opens but the contains in it doesn't slide down or up when click, might be something that i didn't include on my website, that making it not to work because it works fine on fiddle

Comment: No it's nothing to do with the jQuery library you are using, i checked it with the version 1.7.2 you are using on site and it works fine in fiddle check here http://jsfiddle.net/e3w07hxh/3/

Comment: What exactly you wana do with the menu you open it on hover or click?

Comment: open it on click and close it on click on it or another link

Comment: i just want it to work on my website just the way it working on Fiddle

Comment: if you open my website you will see that it is not working

Comment: change this in your `bootstrap css` file `.hidden {
    display: none!important;
}` to `.hidden {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: yeah i checked it and found the issue, its the css selector in above comment with `!important` rule which causing the menu not shwoing

Comment: i have removed the .hidden { display: none!important } to .hidden { display: none; } but still yet not toggling

Comment: Check here, the snap shot see the `display:block` is cross because display:none !important is not letting it to show the dropdown http://shehary.com/stackimages/hidden.png

Comment: I have 10 more mins here so my suggestion is don't change `.hidden { display: none!important; }` in `bootstrap.min.css` instead rename your custom selector `.hidden` to `.hideme` in CSS and then in HTML replace `hidden` class with `hideme` its the right way to do it, messing with bootstrap.min.css can cause more issues

Comment: try removing the toggle script you put in `main.js` and put it in page, check browser console log for errors, you have 3 jQuery errors

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have 2 elements with the same id eg. `id="domain-menu"`, that's what classes are for.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".menu-toggle").hide();
  $(".parents-toggle > li a").click(function () {
      $(this).parents('.parents-toggle').siblings().find('.menu-toggle').slideUp();
      $(this).siblings(".menu-toggle").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

will do what you're after without any side-effects such as being unable to close a menu.

Note: example also hides the menu-toggles on load rather than using custom hidden class + css

Edit : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzwrwzfr/)

Comment: yeah i have try that but is still not working, but it works fine on Fiddle i don't know why is not working on my website